# Error The apk must be signed with the same certificates

Tags: android, certificate, apk

My last key must have expired as when I tried to upload a new apk which I have done countless times before it has requested I load a new one. However, when I do I get the message above. I'm using the same project name and same key code file but even though I have created about half a dozen new apk files, I still get the same message. I've tried unpuiblishing my app to create a new one but it just tells me I already have an apk with the same name!
Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Package name" is unique identifier of app.
If you want to update existing app, than you should sign apk with the same key, as previous apk.

If you want to create new app you should change package name in mainfest file. This allow you to release new app with 0 downloads, that signed with another key.

Comment: If I change my package name in my manifest file I get a series of errors in my source files as the next entry under appname>src is the old package name and the source files are in that folder but I cant seem to change that name without causing other errors

Comment: You can use any name of src package, but if it differs with manifest packageName - just write full path to activities and services in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

All version of the app that you've upload under the same package have to be signed under same key, as Google say [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) - you can't update you app after the cert is expired.

> "If you plan to support upgrades for a single application, you should
>   ensure that your key has a validity period that exceeds the expected
>   lifespan of that application. A validity period of 25 years or more is
>   recommended. When your key's validity period expires, users will no
>   longer be able to seamlessly upgrade to new versions of your
>   application."