# The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the prebious version

Tags: android, eclipse, keystore

I trying to add an updated version of one of older apps (ver 10.0) but when I try to add the apk to the existing apk list I get the message

```
  The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the prebious version
```

I'm definitely using the correct keystore as I have only the one in that folder but I then tried to unpublish the old one and add a new application. I update the Version Code to 11 and
the Version Name to 10.1 created a new apk file but when I tried to add as new i then got the message

```
  If you have another application on Google Play with the same package name (org.MyApp). Go to that application and click upgrade
```

I don't know what to try next as every entry I've seen with this problem tells me I'm using the wrong keystore but I'm not. How can I get around the second error, if I just change the package name it crashes when I download it

Comment: If you are using the correct certificate, you will not see this error. Make sure that you're uploading the apk you signed for release, and not the debug one from the /bin folder

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error The apk must be signed with the same certificates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841767/error-the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definetely sounds as if you're using the wrong keystore. This needs to be the same you used when you first published the app.

You can't publish a new app with the same package name as google requires every app to have a unique package name.

If you were to publish the original app with the new package name you would have to tell your existing users to move to the new app.

Comment: If I need the original keystore and the only one I have doesn't work my only option is the last one. I did try changing the package name in the manifest but when I rebuilt I had errors from the app name down through src to all the source code files. the folder layout below src is org>old package name, which probably is the problem but then if I change that I get different erros

Comment: If you changed the package name but then got build errors it may not have refactored the package name. If you just changed it within the manifest this won't work. You would need to right click on the project > android Tools > Rename package (and this should refactor across all of the code). The keystore that you are using unfortunately can't be the correct version, the only reason for this error to occur is if the keystore doesn't match was was originally used when first published.

Comment: Thank you I was able to rename the package correctly and load it as a new app